# Why is $\lim_{x \to ∞} {(\frac{x}{x-1})^x}=e$

Tags: calculus, limits

Hey guys so I had a quiz a couple days ago and lost partial marks for the following limit:

$$\lim_{x \to ∞} f(x) = \left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)^x$$

The way I solved it was by applying $\ln$ to get that $x$ down, and after some algebra got the limit $=\dfrac{0}{0}$; I applied L'hospital's Rule and got $1$; why my TA says that the answer is $e$?

Comment: If $\lim_{x\to\infty} \ln f(x) = 1$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = e^1 = e$.

Comment: Well that's true, I still think I shouldn't have lost marks for it but can't argue that; gotta go back to read the book then

Comment: Well, the loss of marks is beyond what I can do here.

Comment: why the massive downvotes? The question is clear and appropriate.

Comment: @Masacroso  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the reciprocal. Then
$$
\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)^x=\left(
1-\frac{1}{x}
\right)^x\to e^{-1}
$$
as $x\to \infty$ by a well-known characterization of the exponential function. In particular the original limit is then $e$.

Comment: Very nice trick!

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

We have

$${\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)^x}={\left(1+\frac{1}{x-1}\right)^x}=\frac{{\left(1+\frac{1}{x-1}\right)^x}}{{\left(1+\frac{1}{x-1}\right)}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{x-1}\right)}=\ldots$$

**Edit**: to complete the answer

$$\ldots={\left(1+\frac{1}{x-1}\right)^{x-1}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{x-1}\right)}\to e \cdot 1 =e$$

Comment: Yeah doing the limit wasn't the problem though, but rather my final answer which was $1$ and correct, why the answer has to be exactly $e$. But it got answered in one of the comments.

Comment: @S.. As you can see the expression is equal to $${\left(1+\frac{1}{x-1}\right)^{x-1}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{x-1}\right)}$$ and by$ x-1=y \to \infty$ by the definition of $e$ $$ {\left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)^{y}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)} \to e \cdot 1=e $$

Comment: @S.. Please reselect and accept the other answer, I didn't edited the question for that! Ionly want to be sure You got the method. It seems not correct to me gain an answer after editing. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The other $2$ answers have shown you how you can approach the problem but haven't addressed why your approach was faulty. If you *did* take the log of both sides, you'd get:

$$\begin{aligned}L&=\lim\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)^x\\
\ln L&=\lim \left[x\ln\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)\right]\\
&=\lim \left[x\ln\left(x\right)-x\ln\left(x-1\right)\right]
\end{aligned}$$

As far as I can see, this doesn't lead you to anything of the form $\frac{f}{g}$, with $\lim f=\lim g=0$ or $\pm\infty$. Hence, we couldn't apply L'Hopital's rule. My guess is that you erroneously distributed the log with $\ln\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)\neq\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(x-1)}$. Or possibly, you didn't take the log of the base, $\frac{x}{x-1}$, when you took logs of both sides of the limit. In any case, the other answers give the correct ways to proceed with the problem.

Comment: For posterity, you *can* manipulate that into the form $\frac{f}{g}$ if you use the substitution $x\mapsto \frac1u$. So then $\frac{f(u)}{g(u)}=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)-\ln\left(\frac{1}{u}-1\right)}{u}$ and $\frac{f'(u)}{g'(u)}=\frac{1}{\left(1-u\right)}$ so $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f'(u)}{g'(u)}=1$, which would prove the limit but I don't know if that's what you did.